# How to create oAuth in instagram?

Tags: ios, api, oauth, instagram

i have some problem with my uAuth instagram for iOS app. So i want to create automatic like for any photos in instagram. But i have problem with my oAuth, i already create account in insta for development, and when i start to my app i have this error:

{"code": 400, 
"error_type": "OAuthException", 
"error_message": "Redirect URI does not match registered  redirect URI"}

So what i doing wrong? It's problem with my code or it's problem with instagram API? Please help me. I read many topics about it but, all peoples have the same error and nothing to find best solution.

It's not good for paste all my class of project...Thanks for help

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]You Need To Provide The Redirect URi Like

```
AppName://
```

At http://instagram.com/developer/clients/manage/

Comment: Look on the picture, where i must to add AppName?

Comment: Aaa okey so i found but what name i must write?

Comment: if you are confused theb go to the build setting and search the "product name", It's Your app name. let say my App name is Facebook, Then The Redirect URI will be Facebook://

Comment: See the Example Above

Comment: Very interesting, because i changed app name in my project and in manage but this error repeat...